# How to create a Tab that shows sub-menu on Click in salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, tab, custom-view

I have a tab in my salesforce instance named as **RelationShip Modules**.
I want to add custom functionality on this tab, when I click on tab, it should display sub-menu with Modules Names **Leads**, **Accounts**, **Contacts** etc.

When I click on one value i.e. module name like **Leads**, it should open its list view. then all other functionality should be same.
I want to get something like this:

[image]

Here when I click on Tab **Client Relationships**, It should show me menu same as shown in figure above.

Is it possible in salesforce by using Visualforce or any thing else?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The tabs can be over-written with a complete new Visualforce page and you can do all sorts of customization in that page BUT I don't see a way of doing the Dropdown sub-menu on the Tab link itself.  Because, unfortunately you cannot access the Tab hover properties even if the Tab is over-written by a visaulforce page.

**Alternative Solution:** You could probably create a new menu dropdown after landing on the Visualforce page only

Comment: You got my problem very well.

Now please tell me, with which apex:(Parameter) I can make a menu dropdown?? 
And I dont want to show sub-menu onHover the tab, but I want to show sub-menu on click of tab.

Comment: Is it like to create a dropdown list?

Comment: <apex:tabPanel> is for your inside menu.  This should be inside an <apex:page>

Comment: But this does not fulfill my requirements. 
Is there any other option?

Answer (score 2):

You can make your page start with an [apex:tabPanel](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_tabPanel.htm), so the standard Salesforce tabs are the menu and your own tabs in your page act as the sub-menu.

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: I tried to do this, but it is not working.
It gives me error as "Problem: <apex:page> is required and must be the outermost tag in the markup at line 1 column 1
".

Comment: @KhawajaM.Awais The documentation includes a working example. Any Visualforce page must start with an apex:page tag.

Comment: Yeah I know, but you asked to do so, So I tried it.

Comment: @KhawajaM.Awais OK. I should have said "make your page content (inside an apex:page) start with".

Comment: I had done that Already.
This is good when we have many sub-tabs in a records detail view.

In this context, it was not looking nice.

Comment: I have edited my question which will make it more clear.
Please see it and suggest me if it is possible.

Comment: @KhawajaM.Awais In you updated question, if "Client Relationships" is a standard Salesforce tab button you will not be able to modify it as that part of the page is served from a different domain than your Visualforce and Salesforce have blocked most/all hacks to get around that. All you can control is what is presented within your page's part of the screen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40651/discussion-between-khawaja-m-awais-and-keith-c).

Comment: @KhawajaM.Awais Not something I want to invest the time in - good luck.